# Garage Door - Hinge Broken

Tags: garage-door-opener, hinges, garage-door

My garage door is 10 years old. Recently I noticed that a hinge is broken/snapped (as pointed by arrow). I couldn't find any such part online or in Home Depot. Few questions:

1. What is this part called (if not hinge)?
2. Can I replace it with a regular hinge?
3. When we take the metal sheet screws out, can we still use them or do we need one (or two) size bigger ones? I don't prefer carriage bolts, as I need to drill them from outside.
4. Also, I noticed when I open my garage door after sometime then I hear a slightly heavy sound (of engaging), and subsequent opens/shuts are very smooth. Also when I disconnect garage door opener, and open manually, it is always smooth even opening after 24 hours. And then when I connect opener again, it is smooth. (see 2nd part of picture for reference).
5. Last but not the least, during painting my garage door, I kind of broken one of the glasses when putting it back. Where can I get a replacement piece?

[image: Configuration] [image: Garage Door]

Comment: Home cheapo ain't gonna have it. Any garage door supplier will.

Answer (score 2):

Do an Internet search for "garage door sales near me". A garage door store will have your replacement hinge and glass. As for the heavy sound, since I have not heard it, it's impossible to diagnose. I would suggest that you oil all of the hinges and rollers once a year or so to help eliminate any binding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To summarize your answer in point form. 1) Yes it is called Hinge, 2) No for Regular Hinge, 3) Ans still pending, 4) You can't say 5) Garage door supplier